# Laravel sum column in table

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have two tables:

```
LECTURES
id   name
1 - Lesson 1
2 - Lesson 2
3 - Lesson 3

LECTURESTYPE
id  id_lectures   numb
1 -     1 -        10
2 -     2 -        20
3 -     1 -        30
```

How can I sum numbs column for each lesson and take result like : name: Lesson 1 numb: 40

I want to display the sum of numb for each lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LECTURESTYPE::with('lectures')->sum('numb')->GroupBy('id_lectures')->get()`

Comment: what realtionship i need to put in models

Comment: For LECTURESTYPE model : `public function lectures(){ return $this->hasMany('App\LECTURES','id_lectures'); }`

Comment: Call to a member function groupBy() on double

Answer (score 0):

You need the following relation:

**Lecture (App\Lecture.php)**

```
namespace App;
class Lecture extends Model {
    protected $table = 'lectures';
    public function lecturetype() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LectureType');
    }
}
```

**LectureType (App\LectureType.php)**

```
namespace App;
class LectureType extends Model {
    protected $table = 'lecturestype';
    public function lecture() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Lecture');
    }
}
```

Now you can try in the Controller:

```
$sum = App\LectureType::with('lecture')->GroupBy('id_lectures')->sum('numb');
```

Comment: $sum = App\LectureType::with('lecture')->GroupBy('id_lectures')->sum('numb');

Comment: only back to me number 10 no array

Answer (score 0):

Try `LECTURESTYPE::with('lectures')->GroupBy('id_lectures')->sum('numb')`